# Scheduled task not working

Tags: windows, scheduled-tasks, drupal

I would like to make a scheduled task on my server which will visited a URL every 10 minutes.
(It's a cron job for my Drupal website, so there is no spam-alert or something :))

I've set up a task, but for some reason, the task won't go to the URL... What do I do wrong?

[image]

[image]

The URL to go to is `http://www.example.com/cron.php?cron_key=azerty`

When I trigger the task, Firefox won't even open and I get a status `(0x1)`...

Comment: So what happens after the scheduled run time? Does Firefox launch? Does the task give an unsuccessful error code?

Comment: Sorry, I've updated my question

Answer (score 1):

Place quotes `" "` around the URL in the `Add arguments` box.

As a side note, a full Firefox session seems to be a bit of a resource hog just hit a URL every ten minutes. Have you considered a text browser, such as [elinks](http://www.paehl.com/open_source/?TextBrowser_for_Windows)?

Comment: Thanks. I'll add the quotes. What do you mean by elinks? Because the link you gave is a 404...

Comment: I updated the URL. Here it is directly. http://www.paehl.com/open_source/?TextBrowser_for_Windows

Comment: And it will just go to the url in stead of opening a Browser session?

Comment: It does open a browser, but it's text based browser. It opens in a command prompt window. The benefit is lower memory consumption.

Comment: Ok, great! I'll try it when I get back to the office! I'll get in touch. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

According to Mozilla, your command-line syntax is not correct. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Command_Line_Options

Comment: I don't see what's wrong...